# Call static method from generic abstract class without specifying a type

Tags: c#, generics, static, abstract-class

I have an abstract class like this:

```
public abstract class BaseCamera<TCamera> : ICamera where TCamera : ManagedCameraBase
{
    public static uint GetNumberOfCameras()
    {
        using (var bus = new ManagedBusManager())
        {
            bus.RescanBus();
            return bus.GetNumOfCameras();
        }
    }
}
```

And want to call it like this:
`BaseCamera.GetNumberOfCameras()`

It makes sense to me, because since this is an abstract class, only the concrete children classes must choose a `TCamera`, and the base class wants to get the number of all cameras, no matter they type.

However, the compiler does not approve:

> Using the Generic type 'BaseCamera' requires 1 type
>   arguments.

Is there some way around it or do I need to create a new class just for this?

I think it is worth pointing out that `ManagedCameraBase` is a class from an external API I'm wrapping. Therefore, I do not want to include it in any of my calls for `BaseCamera` and that is why I'm trying to avoid specifying a type.

Comment: Well the fact that your error message refers to a type you haven't shown us makes it really hard to help you... please provide a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet oops, fixed it

Comment: Did you try `BaseCamera<ManagedCameraBase>.GetNumberOfCameras()`?

Comment: Make `BaseCamera<TCamera>` inherit from a non-generic `BaseCamera` class that has your static method. Otherwise you have to give `BaseCamera<TCamera>` a type argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the problem. The static method `GetNumberOfCameras` belongs to the class that contains it, but a generic class actually gets compiled into separate classes for each type. So, for example if you had this:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    static int foo = 0;

    public static void IncrementFoo()
    {
        foo++;
    }

    public static int GetFoo()
    {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

And then you did this:

```
Foo<string>.IncrementFoo();
Console.WriteLine(Foo<string>.GetFoo());
Console.WriteLine(Foo<int>.GetFoo());
```

You will see that the first call to `GetFoo` will return one, but the second will return zero. `Foo<string>.GetFoo()` and `Foo<int>.GetFoo()` are *two separate static method* that belong to *two different classes* (and access two different fields). So that's why you need a type. Otherwise the compiler won't know which static method of which class to call.

What you need is a non-generic base class for your generic class to inherit from. So if you do this:

```
public class Foo<T> : Foo
{

}

public class Foo
{
    static int foo = 0;

    public static void IncrementFoo()
    {
        foo++;
    }

    public static int GetFoo()
    {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Then this:

```
Foo<string>.IncrementFoo();
Console.WriteLine(Foo<string>.GetFoo());
Console.WriteLine(Foo<int>.GetFoo());
```

Will give you what you might have expected at first. In other words, both calls to `GetFoo` will return the same result. And, of course, you don't actually need the type argument anymore and can just do:

```
Foo.IncrementFoo();
```

Or course, the alternative is to just move your static methods into an entirely different class if there's no reason why it should be part of `BaseCamera`

Comment: Thanks! The extra class to inherit from does seems to add unnecessary complexity.
So, with I would create a new class for holding helper methods like this, is there a naming convention? I'm thinking `CameraHelper` or `CameraManager`, but not sure.

Answer (score 3):

> because since this is an abstract class, only the concrete children classes must choose a `TCamera`

That's not how generics work.  This has nothing at all to do with the class being `abstract`.  If the class was generic and *not* abstract you would *still* need to specify a generic argument in order to call a static method of the class.  On top of that, there's nothing to say that a child class can't *also* be generic.  Yours may happen to not be, but there's nothing requiring that to be the case.

Now, in your particular case, the `GetNumberOfCameras` method doesn't use the generic argument (`T`) at all, so *it doesn't matter* what generic argument you provide, you can put in whatever you want and it'll work just fine.  Of course, because of that, it's a sign that this method probably doesn't belong in this class; it should probably be in another class that this class also uses.

Comment: Well - not *whatever* type for the type parameter, given the type constraint ;)

Comment: For this particular case, it is true that calling it with different types will yield the same result. However, the normal expectation for a static class would be that a single instance serves all requests, which suggests there might be some sort of state kept within, in which case the result could potentially be different as using different types will result in different instances being created, one for each type passed.

Comment: @DigiFriend Sure, it also needs to be a valid type, and in scope, and accessible, and so on.  That's not the point; the point is that the generic type specified doesn't affect the method, so any type that lets the code compile is fine.

Comment: @Juan *Most* `static` methods tend to be stateless.  It's usually concerning to see static state, as opposed to a pure method, like this one, and you'd expect the method to make it very clear that that's happening if it really is relying on static state, which it's not.

Comment: @Servy I personally dislike static methods for various reasons, this being one of them. However, I have seen it heavily used in a stateful manner, specially for Singleton implementations. Either way, making a method that can take "any" parameter and produce the same result is not very logical anyways. Why have a method that requires a type when the type is not used at all? That to me is a GIANT red flag.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the "it should probably be in another class **that this class also uses.**"? Thanks!

Comment: @Juan Like I said, this static method *should* be in another class, precisely because it *doesn't* rely on the generic argument.  That's not a reason for it to be an instance method though.  The fact that other people abuse `static` methods to hold state in situations where they shouldn't doesn't mean you shouldn't use them when they're appropriate, as appears to be the case here.

Comment: @GabrielJ You create a new class, and you put that method in that new class, then you call the method in that class, rather than calling it using the class you showed here.

Comment: @Servy I am curious. What makes you think it's a good idea to use a static method here?

Comment: @Juan Because it doesn't rely on any instance state.  Why would you make a method an instance method when it doesn't rely on any instance data?

Comment: Thank you @Servy! Wish I could accept both your answers!

Comment: @Servy Lack of reliance on instance state does not necessarily mean it should be static.

Comment: @Servy I'll tell you what I see. I see a method that does nothing but instantiate a class and call two methods which are clearly coupled. The second method needs the first one to run first, which indicates an issue with the design of that API since that should have been encapsulated into a single call that handles that aspect internally. I personally would keep an instance of the manager at a higher level and use it to call the combined method. If for some reason the preference is to keep a static method, it should be the combined method and belong to the manager class itself.

Comment: @Servy Sorry for the long comments. Ultimately, static methods can be hard to test when you have internal dependencies like the OP does (the manager class).

Comment: @Juan Sure it does.  That's the whole point of `static`; it's to say that it's not tied to a specific instance.  Why in the world would you have a method that you require an instance for that you then proceed to ignore and not use?

Comment: @Juan Static methods are no harder to test.  You have one *less* dependency to worry about, not any more.

Comment: @Juan `static` isn't in any way contrary to the idea of "object oriented".  Good OO programming doesn't involve marking static methods as instance methods only to ignore the object instance.

Comment: @Servy OK, so let's say I want to use an interface so I can swap managers without having to change the internal code of this class. How would I do that with this method when implemented as static? How would I test this method without a real implementation of the Manager class (mocking)? We have created a dependency that cannot be provided to the static instance unless another static class is used.

Comment: @Juan That has nothing to do with the method being instance or static, that's simply down to whether you take the manager as a parameter or create it internally.  If it's important for the sake of your code that you be able to provide different managers, then you make it a parameter and take in the manager, if it isn't, then you don't.  Either way, you still haven't provided any reason for the method to be an instance method.

Comment: @Servy So if I pass the manager to a piece of code that will simply call a method on it, why not just call the method outside instead of passing the parameter?

Comment: @Juan Now you're arguing that the method doesn't do enough to be worth making a method out of it, which you're more than welcome to argue, but you still haven't provided any reason for the method to be an instance method.  Making the method an instance method isn't solving any of the problems you're raising, those problems are all with entirely unrelated facets of the method.

Comment: @Juan I understand you are making general points, but in this specific case, `ManagesBusManager` is from an external API I have no control over. If you were to create a helper class containing the presented method, you still wouldn't make it static?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are a couple of things here you need to understand better.

First of all, I see a problem with your design. The method you are attempting to stick into this class really has nothing to do with the generic nature of it. In fact, you are instantiating another class to do the job so it really does not belong here at all.

If it actually had something to do with an object that inherits from ManagedCameraBase, the method would probably not need to be static but rather an instance method. You can then decide on the accessor (public/private) based on usage.

Finally, you need to understand what Generics actually do under the covers. When you use the generic base with a particular type, an underlying specialized type is created for you behind the scenes by the compiler. If you were to use the static method, the compiler would need to know the type you are targeting in order to create the static instance that will serve your call. Because of this, if you call the static method, you must pass a type and you will end up with as many static instances as the types you use to call it (the types must derive from ManagedCameraBase, of course).

As you can see, you should either move that method out to some helper class or something of the sort, or make it a non-static, instance method.

Comment: Since this is an abstract class and the method is aimed to count the number of *all* cameras, wouldn't putting it as an instance method be even worse design?